# Can't connect to server with SSH. ECDSA key fingerprint is displayed

Tags: authentication, ssh

After trying to connect to the server from a client, using ssh, I got the following message:

[image]

Does it mean the server uses private key for authentication?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This warning simply means that the server's public key is not in your `known_hosts` file - probably because you have never connected to this server before from this client.

If you continue, your ssh client will add the server's public key to your `known_hosts` file as a way of 'pinning' the server's key.  Each subsequent time that you connect to this server, your client will verify that the public key that the server presents matches the one that is 'pinned' in the `known_hosts` file as a way of mitigating MITM attacks.  If so, you won't see this warning again on future connection attempts.

Comment: That's useful. I appreciated your answer.

Comment: 1. It has a name: Trust On First Use. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trust_on_first_use 2. cloud VMs usually have a way to check the host key to detect man in the middle attack even on first connection, it should be used when possible. Accessing git over ssh has the same behavior and the host keys of e.g. github are published so you could verify your first connection. 3. modern ssh should use ed25519 host key instead of ecdsa host key. 4. When cloning a VM, make sure the host key is replaced with a new one.